# Powershell substring cutting

Tags: string, powershell, substring

Is there a function in Powershell that would **cut** values according to given **formatting mask**?

Lets use for example `$test = "Value 14, Code 57"`

```
Cut-Substring("Value $val, Code $code",$test)
```

As the result I would like to receive `$val = 14` and `$code = 57`.

If not, is there an even more powerful tool allowing to access fields **next to given labels**?

Comment: You should not ask for a tool recommendation on _StackOverflow_, but as that is not the entirety of your question I'm not voting to close it.

Answer (score 5):

Um, regex?

```
$test = "Value 14, Code 57"
$test -match 'Value (\d+), Code (\d+)'
$matches[1] #14
$matches[2] #57
```

The power of regexes should allow you to tweak it to your needs.

Comment: +1 for the simple regex. Regexes aren't always the answer, but they are for this situation.

Comment: Thanks, are $matches[] indexed from 1 or 0?

Comment: @PaveArthanis - Indexed from 0 as usual. Just that 0 would be the entire match, in this case, the entire `$test` string. Other would be groups specified in the regex

Answer (score 0):

An alternative.

```
$test = "Value 14, Code 57"
$val,$code=$test -split ',' | ForEach {($_.Trim() -split ' ')[1]}
'$val={0} and $code={1}' -f $val,$code

# Prints
# $val=14 and $code=57
```